# Hide mesh faces while showing vertices/edges in edit mode (Blender 2.8)

Tags: blender

[Update] I've found the answer. For anyone else looking for a similar effect go to the modeling tab -> viewport overlays -> mesh edit mode -> deselect faces

I am in edit mode in the 3D view and my scene looks like the first picture below. I want to hide the faces so I can edit while only seeing the vertices & edges like the wireframe below, but I need to keep the faces as part of the mesh.

If I select the faces and press H to hide them the vertices and edges are hidden too. If I make the mesh a wireframe the faces are removed, not just made invisible.

How can I hide the faces while still showing the vertices and edges?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Blender 2.8: How to use wireframe mode?](https://www.blender3darchitect.com/blender-3d/blender-2-8-how-to-use-wireframe-mode/)

Answer (score 0):

Do Command h on mac and Ctrl on windows, Linux and Chromebook.

Comment: Or Wireframe mode

Comment: Command H on a Mac hides Blender. H hides the selected face.